# Dragging Image in limited area

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using angular js for dragging, rotating and resizing an image but I want to do it in limited area. Here is my code. I can rotate drag and resize it but image goes everywhere. I need to drag it within a specific block.

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
 console.clear();
})
.directive('ionPinch', function($timeout) {
return {
restrict: 'A',
link: function($scope, $element) {

  $timeout(function() {
    var square = $element[0],
        posX = 0,
        posY = 0,
        lastPosX = 0,
        lastPosY = 0,
        bufferX = 0,
        bufferY = 0,
        scale = 1,
        lastScale,
        rotation = 0,
        last_rotation, dragReady = 0;
    ionic.onGesture('touch drag transform dragend', function(e) {
      e.gesture.srcEvent.preventDefault();
      e.gesture.preventDefault();
      switch (e.type) {
        case 'touch':
          lastScale = scale;
          last_rotation = rotation;
          break;
        case 'drag':
          posX = e.gesture.deltaX + lastPosX;
          posY = e.gesture.deltaY + lastPosY;
          break;
        case 'transform':
          rotation = e.gesture.rotation + last_rotation;
          scale = e.gesture.scale * lastScale
          break;
        case 'dragend':
          lastPosX = posX;
          lastPosY = posY;
          lastScale = scale;
          break;
      }
      var transform =
          "translate3d(" + posX + "px," + posY + "px, 0) " +
          "scale(" + scale + ")" +
          "rotate(" + rotation + "deg) ";
      e.target.style.transform = transform;
      e.target.style.webkitTransform = transform;
    }, $element[0]);
  });
}
 };
});
```

Please help me out

Comment: Share your code